# basic authentication with angular

Tags: angular

i have code :

```
 auth(){
this.storage.get('username').then((username) => {
  if(this.username == username){
    this.showAlertRegisterFailed();
  }

  else {
    this.showAlertRegisterSuccess();
  }
})}

doRegister(){
let postParams = {
  nama :this.nama,
  email :this.email,
  username :this.username,
  password :this.password
}

this.storage.set(this.username, postParams).then(
  () => {
    this.auth();
  },
  error => {
    this.showAlertRegisterFailed();
  }
);}
```

can someone check where its wrong...

the code is about register page where if username already it will be show register fail with local storage.

Thanks

Comment: Whats not working and whats wrong ? Provide some explanation mate

Comment: when i input the form and save it to local storage, its success, and then when i input again with same username pop up still display success but not save to local storage, i want to dsplay pop up fail if the username already exists

Comment: is it angularJS or Angular 4/5?

Comment: sorry wrong tag, its Angular 5.2.10

Comment: Can you share `this.storage.set` & `this.storage.get` code.

Comment: Its already on method auth()  and doRegister()